# Can't redirect from jsp to html

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My project structure is as following

```
gk1
  |_src
      |_main
           |_java
                |_resources
                |_webapp
                      |_WEB-INF
                      |_index.jsp
                      |_mcq.jsp
```

my web.xml file looks as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">

  <display-name>gk1</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my index.jsp is as following

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="mcq.jsp">Get on new adventure.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

when i start project, and click on "Get on new adventure." it doesn't redirect me to the mcq.html file. it says the resource is not available. But when i Change the mcq.html to mcq.jsp, it runs fine. What should i do to resolve this. I need to show an html page only.

Answer (score 1):

JSP files are rendered as HTML anyway, so there is no need to have plain HTML files in your server. You can just give a plain HTML file the extension JSP and it will render fine.

Alternatively you could set up a HTML renderer within your servlet, which will render HTML. Views are explained here http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/views.html

Also you shouldn't need to reference a file by its extension, in your link you only need 'mcq' not 'mcq.html'.

The other solution is to put your HTML file in the static resources directory, items in the static resources will not be passed through the renderer (However I would not recommend this method as it can cause your project to become unmanageable).

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, it is just messy and unnecessary.

Comment: @steves165 I have edited the question a bit. The file is mcq.jsp not mcq.html. Can you please help me now? I would need jsp only because I want to take advantage of them.

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/configurewebapp.htm#WBAPP158

> **Accessing Information in WEB-INF**
>
> The WEB-INF directory is not part of the public document tree of the
>   application. **No file contained in the WEB-INF directory can be served
>   directly to a client by the container**. **However, the contents of the
>   WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the getResource
>   and getResourceAsStream() method calls on the ServletContext or
>   includes/forwards using the RequestDispatcher**.

Essentially then you cannot link directly to a resource under WEB-INF. You need to either move your JSP files to some location under webapp root e.g. /webapp/pages/ or, link to a Servlet or Spring Controller which forwards to your JSP resources.

Best practice is never to link directly to JSP files. You are using Spring should should be mapping to a Controller URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must specify **/WEB-INF/mcq.jsp** instead of **mcq.jsp**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/WEB-INF/mcq.jsp">Get on new adventure.</a>
</body>
</html>
```